# AWS ALB HTTPS for SonarQube

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, sonarqube, aws-application-load-balancer

Good day, community.

I want to make a secure connection to SonarQube server using ALB.
We configured alb to listen on port 443 and port 9000 and redirect to a target group that listens on port 9000, but it looks like Jenkins pipeline cannot pass this https. The webpage is accesible through web-browser.

What is the correct way to configure ALB on AWS with https and redirect traffic to the 9000 port on ECS(container service)?

`ERROR: SonarQube server [https://sonar-qa.macropay.mx] can not be reached INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: Total time: 0.475s INFO: Final Memory: 3M/17M INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123) at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74) at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76) ... 7 more Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sonar-qa.macropay.mx: Name or service not known at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:934) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1543) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1385) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1306) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Dns.lambda$static$0(Dns.java:39) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:171) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:135) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:187) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:115) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:99) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39) ... 10 more ERROR:  ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [Pipeline] } WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?`

I like to have a SonarQube server running on ECS behind an ALB with HTTPS and send the data for analyzation from Jenkins server to SonarQube server in secure manner.

The configuration of ALB:

[image: Listeners]

[image: 443 port listener]

[image: 80 port listener]

[image: security group]

[image: target group]

Comment: "`java.net.UnknownHostException: sonar-qa.macropay.mx: Name or service not known`" that looks like a DNS error.  8.8.8.8 resolves it to a CNAME to an ALB, it answers on 443.  Maybe your issue was temporary - dns changes can take a bit of time to propagate.  Otherwise, check why *your* DNS can't resolve it.

Comment: Thank you, @erik258 it turns out that I have to add records in route 53 in each account for private.